# Working with NSClipView NSLayoutConstraints inside NSScrollView

Tags: nsscrollview, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to create a window that contains a scrollView+clipView+actualView that stretches in all directions to the size of the window, but I'm getting nowhere fast, I'm new to constraints and this is my code that scrolls my actualView on window resize...which is not expected...

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)aStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect styleMask:aStyle backing:bufferingType defer:flag];
if (self)
{
    //Create subviews
    _scrollView = [[DocumentScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
    [_scrollView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    _clipView = [[NSClipView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    [_clipView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    _documentView = [[DocumentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
    [_documentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    //Add views
    [_clipView setDocumentView:_documentView];
    [_clipView addSubview:_documentView];
    [_scrollView addSubview:_clipView];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_scrollView];

    //Configure constraints
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_documentView, _scrollView, _clipView);

    [_clipView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_documentView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];

    [_clipView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_documentView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];


    [_scrollView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_clipView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];

    [_scrollView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_clipView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];


    [self.contentView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_scrollView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];

    [self.contentView addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_scrollView]|"
                                             options:0
                                             metrics:nil
                                               views:views]];

    //[self visualizeConstraints:[_scrollView constraints]];

}
return self;
}
```

Anyone know how to get this working?

Kind Regards

Chris

Comment: Have you ever been able to solve this? I'm stuck with pretty much the same problem.

Comment: Ditto. This is too hard and poorly documented.